# IntelliJ is not running Spring Boot Debugger

Tags: java, spring-boot, macos, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a Spring boot project with IntelliJ. Suddenly, my lines do not debug after working for last few years.

It will debug through the class, but when i try to run a method, it will not see the breakpoint. I got an application context message earlier, which I fixed, but its still not working. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.2/spring-support.html#spring-file-set

It will see/execute these lines in the background (like its one another thread), but not will debug/catch the method lines.

```
@Autowired
public EncounterFacade(SuperbillRepository superbillRepository, EncounterRepository encounterRepository) {
    this.superbillRepository = superbillRepository;
    this.encounterRepository = encounterRepository;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the code you are running was produced from the source you are viewing?

Comment: hi @tgdavies I believe so, I deleted my whole git repo, and refetched files

Comment: Am I right that "println" is working here and prints a message to the log? 
Do you have the "suspend all threads" option enabled for the breakpoint? https://i.imgur.com/8bLmdYj.png

Comment: ok @KonstantinAnnikov I am using mac, placed resolution below,  in Windows they have port application status bar in lower right of start menu, Mac couldn't tell yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently using a Mac system. It was already running Local host port in the background,

Ran `npx kill-port 8080` to resolve the issue and it worked.